# I am getting "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead."

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to parse JSON from some weather API but i am receiving such error when trying to decode in one of my model's type. I've tried some JSON parser to "improve" my struct but i am still getting this error.
My main struct is:

```
struct LocationData: Codable {
    
    let name: String
    let local_names: LocalNames
    let lat: Double
    let lon: Double
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
    case localNames = "local_names"
    case lat
    case lon
}

struct LocalNames: Codable {
    let ru: String
    let id: String
}
```

I am using this struct to get the needed data (lattitude and longitude) to later pass it to interface:

```
struct CurrentLocation {
    
    let lattitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    
    init?(CurrentLocationData: LocationData) {
        lattitude = CurrentLocationData.lat
        longitude = CurrentLocationData.lon
    }
}
```

And this is original JSON:

```
[
{
"name": "London",
"local_names": {},
"lat": 51.5073219,
"lon": -0.1276474,
"country": "GB",
"state": "England"
},
{},
{},
{},
{}
]
```

Unfolded JSON is accessible here:
https://pastebin.com/ZFn2vLUd
Please, help me to understand what am i missing here?

I've tried multiple struct patterns but all failed to work. I've found the solution with using typealias and a [Array] for my struct but it fails for a sub struct

```
struct LocationDatum: Codable {
    
    let name: String
    let local_names: LocalNames
    let lat: Double
    let lon: Double
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
    case localNames = "local_names"
    case lat
    case lon
}

struct LocalNames: Codable {
    let ru: String
    let id: String
}

typealias LocationData = [LocationDatum]




struct CurrentLocation {
    
    let lattitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    
    init?(CurrentLocationData: LocationData) {
        lattitude = CurrentLocationData.lat
        longitude = CurrentLocationData.lon
    }
}
```

with this error:
Value of type 'LocationData' (aka 'Array') has no member 'lat'
Here's my decoding method:

```
func parseJSONLocation(withData data: Data) -> CurrentLocation? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let locationData = try decoder.decode([LocationData].self, from: data)
            guard let currentLocation = CurrentLocation(CurrentLocationData: locationData) else {
                return nil
            }
            return currentLocation
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(String(describing: error))
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Which return next error if i am trying to use [LocationData].self instead of LocationData.self
Cannot convert value of type '[LocationData]' to expected argument type 'LocationData'

Comment: This kind of typealias is confusing because it suggests a single object. It's not. Delete it and use `LocationData` as single object. By the way the `CodingKeys` must be located **inside** the strucrt and it's recommended to declare it as `private`. And in `CurrentLocation` delete the question mark and replace `CurrentLocationData` just with `data`.

Comment: ..and regarding the DecodingError: I have no idea what you are going to decode, but the error says you might decode `[Something].self` rather than `Something.self`

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments. **Edit** the question.

Comment: Thank you!
Edited the question to cover decoding method and error while trying to use [] type

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your exact end result but let me help you with this error
as the error is very clear

> Value of type 'LocationData' (aka 'Array') has no
> member 'lat'

In initializer you passed **LocationData** which is an array of **LocationDatum** and now are directly trying to access lat long from an array which is not possible you must specify a index like

> lattitude = CurrentLocationData[0].lat ?? 0.0

or pass a single object of LocationDatum as a parameter whatever based on your requirement.

by the way, I used this model based on your provided JSON

```
struct LocationDatum : Codable {
    let name : String?
    let local_names : Local_names?
    let lat : Double?
    let lon : Double?
    let country : String?
    let state : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case name = "name"
        case local_names = "local_names"
        case lat = "lat"
        case lon = "lon"
        case country = "country"
        case state = "state"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        local_names = try values.decodeIfPresent(Local_names.self, forKey: .local_names)
        lat = try values.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .lat)
        lon = try values.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .lon)
        country = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .country)
        state = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .state)
    }
}

struct Local_names : Codable {
    let ru : String?
    let id : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case ru = "ru"
        case id = "let"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        ru = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .ru)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
    }

}
```

Comment: Optional properties and `decodeIfPresent` is redundant.